# system.profile.nscanned shows wrong value?

Tags: mongodb

when i do `db.system.profile.find(...)` query it looks that mongodb shows wrong nscanned value (not of index it used).

if for example i'm for some query `db.c.find(q).explain` getting

```
{
"cursor" : "index multi",   
"isMultiKey" : false,   
"n" : 23,   "nscannedObjects" : 23,     
"nscanned" : 5133,  
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 41042,  
"nscannedAllPlans" : 51297, 
}
```

db.system.profile.find() returns for me `"nscanned" : 51297,` . So as i see it returns nscannedAllPlans. Is it right? Can i see in some way real nscanned of executed (in the past) slow query?

Really, i just want to know if it used the proper index when executed the query.

Comment: Well yeah that is scanned All Index Plans, it is bound to be higher, also nscanned is 5133 not 51297, that is scanned all plans

Comment: Can you include the actual query as well as the MongoDB server version? It is more likely that the `nscanned` value is higher than expected because the query cannot use an index efficiently (for example, if you are using a case-insensitive [regular expression](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)). It would also be helpful to have the full explain output as you are missing the `nscannedObjects` value (which would show how many documents had to be scanned for your query).

Comment: sorry it is not formatted well, "nscannedObjects" : 23,

Comment: and in explain it shows that it use index efficiently....in db.system.profile it shows that it doesn't

Comment: and the query looks like ```“time" : {

"$gte" : ISODate("2014-07-24T08:58:12Z"),

"$lt" : ISODate("2014-07-25T04:58:12Z")

},

“someId" : ObjectId("5213cd2dd19ae0ee17004ae6"),

“someText" : /^a/```